# Browse For Folder dialog window handle C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get the handle HWND of the dialog which user open when clicking on a button.
I'm using Spy++ to find the window class and tittle, but it says that no such window is found. And how then to get the handle of that dialog in C++ using Win API ?

I hope that I will be able to do that using simple functions as FindWindow, GetParent, any WIN APi function. I do not like to inject something or load DLL. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

the folder browser dialog is opened by other program. I want to get it's handle from different  program , my program. Thanks. 
The closest to want i need is for now the function WindowFromPoint

Comment: This could help. I can confirm it works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx

Comment: @chris Hi, is there other way, without injecting DLL or without hooks ? thanks

Comment: This hook doesn't require any injection or DLLs. Is your thread the one creating the dialog, or is it another process/thread?

Comment: Well, the accessibility hook is perfect then. It's not much more complex than the functions you mention, is much more robust for discovering windows, doesn't require any injection, and the code's practically all there for you.

Comment: @chris make your comment as answer and I will accept it, it is what i needed, my mistake was that I didn't read all post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Accessibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx) will let you capture window creation events from other processes without DLL injection. You can modify the example to accommodate for the browsing window specifically. Here's an example I made previously to test that is based on the one from the article. Modify it however you wish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void CALLBACK proc(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG obj, LONG child, DWORD thr, DWORD time) {
    if (hwnd && obj == OBJID_WINDOW && child == CHILDID_SELF) {
        switch (event) {
            case EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE: {
                std::cout << "Window created!\n";
                break;
            }

            case EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY: {
                std::cout << "Window destroyed!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    HWINEVENTHOOK hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, nullptr, proc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (hook) {
        UnhookWinEvent(hook);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm able to get the handle of dialog window, but I'm not able to get handle of dialog item Edit control. I want to insert text in it, please help.

Comment: @Jigberto, A simple call of `FindWindowEx(hwndDlg, nullptr, "EDIT", nullptr);` should get it.

Comment: I did that, i can find the handle for EDIT, but I cannot get or set text for EDIT object. `GetWindowText(z, szName, ARRAYSIZE(szName)); `  this function is returning empty value. Do you want me to open this thread as new question and try to help me ?

Comment: @Jigberto, If you don't see anything that can help on Google or anything, try cutting it down to minimal sample code and put it into a new question. Also make sure that if the function fails, you call `GetLastError` to see why.